# Обновление содержимого по ссылкам jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

У меня есть список ссылок разных и блок с id-шником #block, например. Изначально в блоке есть картинка соответствующая первой ссылке. При клике на остальные, картинка в блоке меняется. Ну это чисто теоретически.

Я думаю, что такие ссылки стоит содержать с каким то классом, дабы не было путаницы и споров, а ссылку на картинку держать в атрибуте href и при клике обновлять атрибут src тега img в этом блоке, а для ссылки ретурнить false.

Что мне стоит использовать, какие ф-ии jQuery? Я новичок, поэтому не очень представляю как это будет работать. Может у кого решение даже готовое завалялось?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".myclass").click( function() { $("#block img").attr( "src", $(this).attr("href") ); return false; } );

<div id="#block"><img src="" /></div>
<a href="mypic1.jpg" class="myclass">1</a>
<a href="mypic2.jpg" class="myclass">2</a>
<a href="mypic3.jpg" class="myclass">3</a>
```

приблизительно так...

Comment: fixed: `$(".myclass").click( function( event ) { event.preventDefault(); $("#block img").attr( "src", $(this).attr("href") ); } );`

Answer (score 3):

Почитай про [jQuery селекторы](http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners-selectors/).

Для того чтоб вытянуть данные из блока div с id='block' тебе нужно будет написать одну строчку:

```
var block = jQuery('#block').html();
```

А для того чтоб вставить:

```
jQuery('#block').html("Text");
```

Для вытягивания любого атрибута:

```
var attribut = jQuery('селектор').attr('имя атрибута');
```